# OnKeyListener is not working

Tags: android

I want four edittext to insert data like ABC-0000-0000-0000,for that I applied textwatcher to move forward when one edittext has filled ,it should come backward when delete key has pressed .For that I applied OnKeyListener which is not working below android6.0.1

My code is-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rdDu.png)

```
   editToken_1 =(EditText)alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.number1);
    editToken_2 = (EditText) alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.number2);
    editToken_3 =(EditText)alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.number3);
    editToken_4 = (EditText) alertLayout.findViewById(R.id.number4);

   editToken_1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    editToken_2.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    editToken_3.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
    editToken_4.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

    editToken_1.setOnKeyListener(returnKeyListener);
    editToken_2.setOnKeyListener(returnKeyListener);
    editToken_3.setOnKeyListener(returnKeyListener);
    editToken_4.setOnKeyListener(returnKeyListener);
```

EditText.OnKeyListener returnKeyListener = new EditText.OnKeyListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {

            if (v.getId() == editToken_4.getId() && (TextUtils.isEmpty(editToken_4.getText())) || editToken_4.getSelectionStart()==0) {

                editToken_3.setSelection(editToken_3.getText().length());
                editToken_3.requestFocus();

            }

            if (v.getId() == editToken_3.getId() && (TextUtils.isEmpty(editToken_3.getText())) || editToken_3.getSelectionStart()==0 ) {

                editToken_2.setSelection(editToken_2.getText().length());
                editToken_2.requestFocus();

            }

            if (v.getId() == editToken_2.getId() && (TextUtils.isEmpty(editToken_2.getText())) || editToken_2.getSelectionStart()==0){

                editToken_1.setSelection(editToken_1.getText().length());
                editToken_1.requestFocus();

            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};

TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        Log.d(TAG,"beforeharSequence s "+s+"\nstart "+start+"\ncount "+count+"\nafter "+after);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        Log.d(TAG," OnTextCharSequence s "+s+"\nstart "+start+"\nbefore "+before+"\ncount "+count);

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.d(TAG," afterCharSequence s "+s);

        if (isFilledForFirst(editToken_1) && isFilled(editToken_2) && isFilled(editToken_3) && isFilled(editToken_4)) {
            closeKB();
            return;
        }

        if (isFilledForFirst(editToken_1) && !isFilled(editToken_2)) {

            editToken_2.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (isFilled(editToken_2) && !isFilled(editToken_3)) {

            editToken_3.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if (isFilled(editToken_3) && !isFilled(editToken_4)) {

            editToken_4.requestFocus();
            return;
        }
    }
};
void closeKB() {

    if (getCurrentFocus() != null) {

        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}

private boolean isFilled(EditText editText) {

    if(editText.getText().toString().trim().length()==4 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText()))
    {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText());
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean isFilledForFirst(EditText editText) {

    if(editText.getText().toString().trim().length()==3 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText()))
    {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText());
    }
    return false;
}

String getFinalCodeFromEditTexts() {
    String Token = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s%s%s%s%s%s%s", editToken_1.getText().toString().trim(), space_1.getText().toString().trim(), editToken_2.getText().toString().trim(), space_2.getText().toString().trim(), editToken_3.getText().toString().trim(), space_3.getText().toString().trim(), editToken_4.getText().toString().trim());
    if (Token.length() == 18) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "token is" + Token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter valid Token", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return Token;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `return true;` when the keycode event occur. Without it the listener will not fire.

```
     @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {

            if (v.getId() == editToken_4.getId() && (TextUtils.isEmpty(editToken_4.getText())) || editToken_4.getSelectionStart()==0) {

                editToken_3.setSelection(editToken_3.getText().length());
                editToken_3.requestFocus();

            }

            if (v.getId() == editToken_3.getId() && (TextUtils.isEmpty(editToken_3.getText())) || editToken_3.getSelectionStart()==0 ) {

                editToken_2.setSelection(editToken_2.getText().length());
                editToken_2.requestFocus();

            }

            if (v.getId() == editToken_2.getId() && (TextUtils.isEmpty(editToken_2.getText())) || editToken_2.getSelectionStart()==0){

                editToken_1.setSelection(editToken_1.getText().length());
                editToken_1.requestFocus();
            }
            return true;   //add this
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: I did it but still cursur is not moving backword

Comment: print log inside your seond if condition and also inside `if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)` to see whether the event is called or not

Comment: I applied log ,event is not calling

Comment: Code is working with marshmallow and lollipop ,it is not working with jellybean and kitkat

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581636/android-cannot-capture-backspace-delete-press-in-soft-keyboard