# Detecting Backspace click on Key_Down event in Android soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-edittext, backspace

I have searched for close to 6 months and I can't get a proper code on how to detect a backspace click in an EditText view.

Using the **setOnKeyListener** and doing `if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)` doesn't work for API 14 and above so we can no longer reply on it.

Also I got an answer which seems to work from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19980975/5585069) but it only works for InputType.TYPE_NULL and I need it to be a rich text editor. And all other answers I got from SO are not reliable.

And again using **TextWatcher** won't give me what I want, because I'll want to `return true` in some conditions therefore making the backspace not to delete the character.

I think it's possible to detect backspace click in Android soft keyboard in higher versions of Android, because I see it in the Facebook app. This [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QJeVRlZ8gU0JclWXoZaO-tBdwXVZj3Tn/view?usp=drivesdk) is a 4sec video of how it looks on Facebook, and that's the exact same result I want.

Any idea on how I can get this done?